# Skip input buffer in c?

Tags: c, buffer, ncurses, curses

I am making a small console game and want to allow instant input and output for the player so that they don't have to hit enter after each move. I understand there are already a few solutions that can be found online, most prominently ncurses (I'm on linux), but I have not been able to get anything to work. When I input the code below, I get the message:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x39c): undefined reference to `initscr'

main.cpp:(.text+0x3a3): undefined reference to `stdscr'

main.cpp:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `wgetch'

main.cpp:(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to `endwin'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I understand skipping the input buffer is not standard in C, but any ways around this would be greatly appreciated. I can make the code work by just using `key = getchar();` but as aforementioned, I want to skip the necessary enter key.

```
void move(int key){
  initscr();
  key = getch();
  switch(key){
    case 'w': if (playery > 1){y--;}
    break;
    case 's': if (playery < height - 1){y++;}
    break;
    case 'a': if(playerx > 1){x--;}
    break;
    case 'd': if(playerx < width - 1){x++;}
    break;
    default: grid[x][y] = 'x';
    break;
  }
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: You need to link with `-lncurses` — list it after any object files (or source files).  If the library can't be found,  you'll need to install it.  But you should have the header, which makes it unlikely that you don't have the library.

Comment: "cpp"? Do you mean C++ tag?

Comment: If he includes the header, he'll have to do an `#undef` for "move", as well, since that's a macro in curses.h

Answer (score 0):

You need to **link** with ncurses to make it work. When you include `curses.h` or `ncurses.h`, it includes just the definitions. The actual code is separated, so you have to tell your compiler to add the code to your program.

## Compiling with clang

Use this when compiling C++:

```
clang++ main.cpp -lncurses
```

Use this when compiling C:

```
clang main.c -lncurses
```

**Never** use clang with C++ or clang++ with C. It creates a huge mess.

## Compiling with GNU/gcc

Use this when compiling C++:

```
g++ main.cpp -lncurses
```

Use this when compiling C:

```
gcc main.c -lncurses
```

Again, do **not** interchange those.

---

You say you use C, but you have `main.cpp`, which implies you are using C++. Rename your file to `main.c` or edit your question.

As noted in comments, `ncurses` already has a function named `move`. You should rename your function.

Comment: It looks like you're new to `ncurses`. I would recommend [this](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) howto. It covers some basics and has code samples.